# Why is this such a censored environment?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

Every time I make a comment someone deletes it without explaining why.  I've seen instances where someone is being deliberately rude and every time I reply my comment gets deleted.

Why are we so quick to censor?

Comment: Rude comments should be flagged and ignored. Replying to them tends to generate a snowball effect that requires more cleanup.

Answer (score 20):

When someone is being rude, instead of replying with a rude comment of your own, flag the comment as either "rude or offensive" or "not constructive." (I can see from your flagging history that you know how.)  This is clarified in the [Be nice](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) section of the help center.

Specifically, responding to disagreement with comments like

> You seem butthurt by my comment

and

> If you don't like to have arguments with people you should try avoiding spewing insults in response to viewpoints that you don't agree with.

might feel satisfying to you, but that's not [what comments are for](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

These comments were flagged by other users as "rude or offensive" or "not constructive" and met the [criteria for removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237982#237982), so they were removed.

Comment: I am really wondering why this is being downvoted.

Comment: I'm with you on the first one to be honest (it was a twitch reaction), but my second comment was constructive.  He told me to not argue and I pointed out that he started the argument.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman It's not constructive for purposes of Q&A, which is what this website is about. Comments that are *about arguing* (not about the content of the post) have no place here. Just flag and disengage.

Comment: But that's not a solution.  People can just take pot-shots without repercussion, which leads to dissatisfaction.  I provided a useful insight based on my experience, and some asshole came and told me I must be a failure.  It doesn't bode well for the site if people can do this without repercussions; eventually anyone with a contrarian opinion will be pushed away.

Comment: @Captain Flag comments containing "pot-shots" and if there's something wrong with them, they'll be removed. Too many of such flags will lead to a suspension for the user who posted the comments. Those are "repercussions" that make the site better for everyone; engaging in argument makes the site worse for others.